# Nested for loop to edit data in a list containing data frames

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe, nested

I have the following data:

```
rand.sum <- function(n){
x <- sort(runif(n-1))
c(x,1) - c(0,x)
}

M <- t(replicate(8,rand.sum(8))) # data frame with probabilities

Test1 <- as.data.frame(t(replicate(1, rand.sum(8))))
Test2 <- as.data.frame(t(replicate(1, rand.sum(8))))
Test <- rbind(Test1,Test2) # Test data

ID1 <- c("ID1")
ID2 <- c("ID2")
ID <- rbind(ID1,ID2) #ID's

data <- cbind(ID,Test)
```

Now I wrote the following for-loop to create a list with matrices:

```
for(i in 1:dim(Test)[1]) { 
z <- i
gemeindeschluessel <- paste(data[z,1])
gemeinden[[gemeindeschluessel]] <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=1,ncol=8))
}
```

This one works fine. Now I want to add data to the data frames in the list using the following nested for loop:

```
for (j in length(gemeinden)){ 
y <- j
for (i in dim(gemeinden[[y]])[2]){
gemeinden[[y]]  [,i]=round(data[y,2]*M[1,i]+data[y,3]*M[2,i]+data[y,4]*M[3,i]
                       +data[y,5]*M[4,i]+data[y,6]*M[5,i]+data[y,7]*M[6,i]
                       +data[y,8]*M[7,i]+data[y,9]*M[8,i])}
}
```

However, this one does not do anything and the data frames in the list are still filled with NAs. I can`t figure out why this is not working.

How can I get this nested for loop to run?

Comment: You need to add `1:` to your bottom loops. Your earlier loops correctly use, e.g., `for(i in 1:dim(Test)[1])`, but your bottom loops leave out the `1:`, `for (j in length(gemeinden))` is equivalent to `for (j in 2)`. You need `for (j in 1:length(gemeinden))` and `for(i in 1:dim(...))`.

Comment: @Gregor Thank you very much! Somehow I missed that. Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gregor pointed out with your slight overlook of not initializing your loop's sequences, consider combining your `for` loops into nested `apply` loops. Notice same `as.data.frame` and `matrix` calls are still used.

The advantage with this approach is you can directly assign your list to `lapply` output and avoid the multiple `+` element additions for vectorized `sum()` across margins:

```
gemeinden_new <- lapply(1:dim(Test)[1], function(z)
                   as.data.frame(
                         matrix(sapply(1:8, function(i) sum(data[z,2:9] * M[,i])),
                                nrow=1, ncol=8)
                   ))

# NAME LIST ELEMENTS 
gemeinden_new <- setNames(gemeinden_new, data$ID)

gemeinden_new   
# $ID1
#          V1        V2         V3        V4         V5        V6         V7       V8
# 1 0.0598796 0.1526457 0.08604147 0.2314867 0.06307882 0.2047462 0.07962943 0.122492

# $ID2
#          V1        V2         V3        V4         V5        V6         V7        V8
# 1 0.1385492 0.1047066 0.06278719 0.1710685 0.09209054 0.2519348 0.06434532 0.1145178

all.equal(gemeinden, gemeinden_new)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!